# MySQL - Adding up columns and displaying per record

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I have this query

```
select articles.articleID, user_votes.tagID, user_votes.count from  articles 
left join article_tags on article_tags.articleID = articles.articleID
inner join user_votes on user_votes.tagID = article_tags.tagID
```

and it returns the following

```
"articleID" "tagID" "count"
    "1"       "1"     "2"
    "1"       "2"    "-5"
    "1"       "3"     "7"
    "2"       "1"     "2"
    "3"       "1"     "2"
    "4"       "1"     "2"
    "6"       "1"     "2"
    "7"       "1"     "2"
```

I want to be able to have it return where it says the articleID, and then has the count added up for each tagID for that article.

So instead of showing articleID 3 times, with 3 tags, and 3 values, it'd show

```
"1", "this doesn't matter", "4" 
"2", "...", "2"
"3". "...", "2"
```

etc

I tried using sum, I tried using cases, but I could never get it to work.

I've tried:

```
select articles.articleID, SUM(user_votes.count) as totalScore from articles 
left join article_tags on article_tags.articleID = articles.articleID
left join user_votes on user_votes.tagID = article_tags.tagID
```

and it returns

```
articleID, totalScore
    1          452
```

Which is every count added up for every article.

Hopefully this makes sense and is an easy fix. I'm confused!

Thanks in advance.
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the missing `group by`

```
select articles.articleID, SUM(user_votes.count) as totalScore from articles 
left join article_tags on article_tags.articleID = articles.articleID
left join user_votes on user_votes.tagID = article_tags.tagID
group by articles.articleID; -- here
```

Also, try to use aliases, which saves you from typing the full table name everywhere.

```
SELECT 
    a.articleID, SUM(v.count) AS totalScore
FROM
    articles a
        LEFT JOIN
    article_tags t ON t.articleID = a.articleID
        LEFT JOIN
    user_votes v ON v.tagID = t.tagID
GROUP BY a.articleID ; -- here
```

Comment: I worked on this for a good 2 hours and you probably solved in a matter of seconds! You sir or ma'm deserve an ice cream cone!

Comment: @rob Glad I could help. :-)